Как установить VulkanSDK на Replit?
Прошу помочь с установкой VulkanSDK в Replit. Если кто-то уже занимался подобным, подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли поддержка VulkanSDK в этой среде разработки? Я также использую GLFW.
Буду благодарен за информацию о возможных альтернативах(бесплатных). В основном я работаю за компьютером, но в ближайшее время у меня будет ограниченное время для этого. Поэтому хотелось бы иметь возможность работать с кодом и с мобильного устройства, например, с Android. Было бы замечательно, если бы можно было запустить или исправить код с любого устройства.

Подключайтесь к своему компьютеру с устройства на андроид

@user7860670 Здравствуйте, не могли бы вы уточнить через что это можно сделать(только бесплатные сервисы)

Microsoft Remote Desktop например
